# Javascript. Calculating a percentage results in 1% difference

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with some javascript where I am calculating a percentage. It always comes in 1% off:

```
pcOff = parseInt((1-(PriceFrom/PriceFromRRP))*100);
```

PriceFrom and PriceFromRRP are captured from a JSON return and in the case of `PriceFrom = '40.00'` and `PriceFromRRP = '50.00'` pcOff is being set to 19; it should be of 20. Something funny is going on here. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Binary floating point math does strange things sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1-(PriceFrom/PriceFromRRP))*100
```

gives:

```
19.999999999999996
```

When you `parseInt` that, the parser reads digits until it hits a non-digit - i.e. the `19`

---

Your best bet (for this example) would be to divide last:

```
100 - PriceFrom*100/PriceFromRRP
```

```
20
```

This prevents the floating point error appearing in the first place

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` doesn't round. `Math.round` rounds.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this transcript

```
> (1-(40.0/50.0))*100
19.999999999999996

> parseInt(19.999999999999996)
19

> Math.round(19.999999999999996)
20
```

`parseInt` reads as much of a string as it can that can to form an integer, in this case, on the first two characters, 1 and 9, for 19.